# Official documentation for JwtBearer middleware/configuration via appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

Starting with NET 7, one can configure JWT validation values in `appsettings.json`, e.g. as mentioned in [this blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-validate-jwt-dotnet/) (section *Simplified configuration for the JwtBearer middleware*):

```
"Authentication": {
    "Schemes": {
      "Bearer": {
        "Authority": "https://{DOMAIN}",
        "ValidAudiences": [ "{AUDIENCE}" ],
        "ValidIssuer": "{DOMAIN}"
      }
    }
  }
```

I however was unable to find official documentation for this on the Microsoft website. Anyone knows where to find the official documentation on this? How do I know which other properties I could configure here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they don't have an official documentation for this. Right now they are using internal `JwtBearerConfigureOptions` to get section by schema name (in your case "Bearer") [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerConfigureOptions.cs),and populate the `JwtBearerOptions` based on `nameof()`. They just added it to `JwtBearerExtensions` in line [77](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerExtensions.cs).

[PR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/42679) when it was added.
[Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42170) create on github - still open.
[Sample](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/samples/MinimalJwtBearerSample) on GitHub.

You can create a whole appsettings.json section based on their code but I wouldn't be much confident in implementing this right now.

Comment: thanks for those great details. I also share your rating and decided to do it via code and not via appsettings.

Comment: thanks so much for the detail links, etc. -- the "best" docs imho